# dynamic & object ConstructorInfo.Invoke(object[] parameters)

Tags: c#

I get this error.

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: "object" not contains definition for "A"

Its not clear for me

`Invoke` method returns `object`, so tob's type detected like a object. How do i fix this?
By the way, in Schildt's book all did similarly

```
dynamic tob = ci.Invoke(new object[]{10,"hello"});
Console.WriteLine(tob.A());
```

Comment: I have no idea what is being asked here.  At least *try* formatting it so its readable.  This question is a pile of mush.

Comment: You will have more luck at http://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: +++++++  and .......................... don't really help. Also, remove the Russian text and format and improve the english part as best you can.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what class `ci` came from, it is hard to tell what might be wrong, but `ConstructorInfo.invoke` returns type `Object`, but you can cast it to whatever the type actually is, like:

```
var tob = (MyClass)(ci.Invoke(new object[]{10,"hello"}));
```

This is assuming that whatever class `ci` is from actually has a public method named `A`